# Incrementing grouped identifiers

Tags: r

I have example data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("Survey Variable_codes_2022
              D       D1
              A       A1
              B       B1
              B       B3
              B       B2
              E       E1
              B       NA
              E       NA")
```

For the two rows that have `Variable_codes_2022==NA`, I would like to increment the variable code so that it becomes:

```
dat <- fread("Survey Variable_codes_2022
              D       D1
              A       A1
              B       B1
              B       B3
              B       B2
              E       E1
              B       B4
              E       E2"
```

Because the column `Variable_codes_2022` is a string variable, the numbers are not in numerical order.

I have no idea where to start and I was wondering if someone could help me on the right track.

Comment: "the numbers are not in numerical order"  Is this important? Are we incrementing from the last value, or the maximum? Is there potential for multiple missing values in a group?

Comment: FYI "Because it is a string variable, the numbers are not in numerical order." see `stringr::str_sort()`

Answer (score 4):

We could do it this way:

1. grouping
2. arranging and
3. `mutate`.

To keep the original order we could first create and id and then rearrange:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(Survey) %>% 
  arrange(.by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Variable_codes_2022 = paste0(Survey, row_number()))
```

```
  Survey Variable_codes_2022
  <chr>  <chr>              
1 A      A1                 
2 B      B1                 
3 B      B2                 
4 B      B3                 
5 B      B4                 
6 D      D1                 
7 E      E1                 
8 E      E2
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` option using `rleid` like this:

```r
library(data.table)
dat[, Variable_codes_2022 := paste0(Survey, rleid(Variable_codes_2022)), by = Survey]
dat
#>    Survey Variable_codes_2022
#> 1:      D                  D1
#> 2:      A                  A1
#> 3:      B                  B1
#> 4:      B                  B2
#> 5:      B                  B3
#> 6:      E                  E1
#> 7:      B                  B4
#> 8:      E                  E2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- 
structure(list(survey = c("D", "A", "B", "B", "B", "E", "B", 
"E", "B"), var_code = c("D1", "A1", "B1", "B3", "B2", "E1", NA, 
NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000026db10f1ef0>)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(survey) %>% 
  mutate(
    aux1 = as.numeric(stringr::str_remove(var_code,survey)),
    aux2 = cumsum(is.na(var_code)),
    var_code = paste0(survey,max(aux1,na.rm = TRUE)+aux2)
    ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-aux1,-aux2)

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  survey var_code
  <chr>  <chr>   
1 D      D1      
2 A      A1      
3 B      B3      
4 B      B3      
5 B      B3      
6 E      E1      
7 B      B4      
8 E      E2      
9 B      B5
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution with `rowid`.
Added an extra element to the sample so it can be tested against multiple missings

```r
library(data.table)
#> Warning: package 'data.table' was built under R version 4.2.2
dat <- fread("Survey Variable_codes_2022
              D       D1
              A       A1
              B       B1
              B       B3
              B       B2
              E       E1
              B       NA
              E       NA
              E       NA")

dat[, n := as.numeric(substr(
  Variable_codes_2022, nchar(Survey)+1, nchar(Variable_codes_2022)))]

dat[is.na(n),
  Variable_codes_2022 := paste0(Survey, rowid(Survey) + 
    dat[.SD[,.(Survey)], .(m=max(n, na.rm=T)), on = "Survey", by=.EACHI ][,m])]

dat                                                                      
#>    Survey Variable_codes_2022  n
#> 1:      D                  D1  1
#> 2:      A                  A1  1
#> 3:      B                  B1  1
#> 4:      B                  B3  3
#> 5:      B                  B2  2
#> 6:      E                  E1  1
#> 7:      B                  B4 NA
#> 8:      E                  E2 NA
#> 9:      E                  E3 NA
```

Comment: Can be done in one line with `dat[is.na(Variable_codes_2022), Variable_codes_2022 := paste0(Survey, rowid(Survey) + dat[.SD[,.(Survey)], max(as.numeric(substr(
 Variable_codes_2022, nchar(Survey)+1, nchar(Variable_codes_2022))), na.rm=T), on = "Survey", by=.EACHI][[2]])]`